# Setuptools does not install dependencies when packaging [toml project]

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

Guys, I'm trying to package my python project, but when I run the `python3 -m build` command in the terminal, the build run properly, but the dependencies are not being installed

I have the `.toml` file configured as below

```
requires = ["setuptools", "setuptools-scm", "Appium-Python-Client==2.1.2"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

I have also a `setup.cfg` file configured as below

```
[metadata]
name = python-frontend-framework
version = 0.0.1
author = name
author_email = email@gmail.com
description = This package cotains all thre structure to run automated tests in the python frontend framework
long_description = file: README.md
long_description_content_type = text/markdown
url = https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject
project_urls =
    Bug Tracker = https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/issues
classifiers =
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3
    License :: Open
    Operating System :: OS Independent

[options]
package_dir =
    = projects
include_package_data = True
packages = find_namespace:
python_requires = >=3.8
install_requires =
    Appium-Python-Client
    pytest
    selenium=
    pytest-bdd
    webdriver-manager

[options.packages.find]
where = projects
```

I'm just trying to run the command `python3 -m build`, but when I check the dependencies, it was not installed.
The execution succeeded without any problem.
Someone knows how can I fix it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `python -m build` is used to build the _sdist_ and the _wheel_ of the project. It does not install the project.

Comment: Same issue, though I am running `pip install -e .` from directory containing toml and package. Any suggestions?